# How to show ActionBar in a CordovaActivity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Using Worklight 6.2 and the new ActionSender API, I'd like to show the actionbar in the main CordovaActivity of my hybrid app. 
That's in order to manage it by Javascript code, through the new API.

The problem is that getActionBar() returns null, even adding the holo theme and a layout to this activity.

Does somebody have a snippet of code to show me the how to do that?

Regards
Giuseppe

Comment: Are you in fact following this blog post and not succeeding? where? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/native_ui_in_a_hybrid_application_with_worklight_6.2?lang=en

Comment: The getActionBar() in the onCreate() method of HybridActivity returns null. Generally speaking I can't understand how to show the action bar in an activity extending CordovaActivity. I tried to set the Holo theme and apply it to the activity, but I was unlucky. Thanks

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to reproduce the example in the Blog, but the method getActionBar() is returning null.

Comment: Looks like the code in the blog is incomplete; I'll get the author to look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is an interesting functionality and I'd like to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The blog post has been revised](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/native_ui_in_a_hybrid_application_with_worklight_6.2?lang=en) to include the missing pieces. *Follow the instructions again*, it will now work.

The missing pieces were related to the below:

1. Make sure that in your AndroidManifest, the activity doesn't have a theme without a title bar:

   ```
   <activity
           android:name=".HybridActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:launchMode="singleTask"
           android:screenOrientation="sensor"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
           ^ last line should be removed.
   >
   ```
2. Add a preference to Cordova configuration (res/xml/config.xml) to make the title bar be shown:
   `<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true" />`